# Bash script doesn't see SIGHUP?

Tags: bash, signals

I've got the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "We are $$"
trap "echo HUP" SIGHUP
cat    # wait indefinitely
```

When I send `SIGHUP` (using `kill -HUP pid`), nothing happens.

If I change the script slightly:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "We are $$"
trap "kill -- -$BASHPID" EXIT    # add this
trap "echo HUP" SIGHUP
cat    # wait indefinitely
```

...then the script does the `echo HUP` thing right as it exits (when I press Ctrl+C):

```
roger@roger-pc:~ $ ./hupper.sh 
We are 6233
^CHUP
```

What's going on? How should I send a signal (it doesn't necessarily have to be `SIGHUP`) to this script?

Comment: The signal will be delivered and the signal handler will execute when the `cat` process finishes.
Try your original script and press `Ctrl+D` to make the `cat` process exit. While the `cat` process is in the foreground, the `HUP` signal is not acted upon. Try again with `cat` replaced by `read` (a shell built-in).

Comment: Perfect. Does someone fancy turning that into an answer?

Comment: I know it works that way, but I'll let someone who have more insight than me into the whys and wherefores do the answer.

Comment: I used `while true; do read; done` in the end, otherwise entering text causes it to quit as well, and I want it to quit on Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The Bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) states:

> If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for
>   which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the 
>   command  completes.

That means that despite the signal is received by `bash` when you send it, your trap on SIGHUP will be called only when `cat` ends.

If this behavior is undesirable, then either use `bash` builtins (e.g. `read` + `printf` in a loop instead of `cat`) or use background jobs (see [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387857/203203)).

Answer (score 11):

[@xhienne has already explained why](/a/387854), but if you wanted to have the signal acted on straight away (and not exit the script), you could change your code to:

```
#! /bin/bash -
interrupted=true
trap 'interrupted=true; echo HUP' HUP

{ cat <&3 3<&- & pid=$!; } 3<&0

while
  wait "$pid"
  ret=$?
  "$interrupted"
do
  interrupted=false
done
exit "$ret"
```

The little dance with file descriptors is to work around the fact that `bash` redirects stdin to `/dev/null` for commands launched in background.

Comment: Does this work because the code block runs in a subshell?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when you have a trap on EXIT, the script does not wait for an external command to end when it receives a signal. Example script:

```
$ cat test-trap 
#!/bin/bash
echo "We are $$"
trap "echo 'Trapping EXIT'" EXIT
cat
```

Running it:

```
$ ./test-trap
We are 24814
```

Sending it a SIGHUP:

```
$ ./test-trap
We are 24814
# Doing `kill -HUP 24814` in another terminal
Trapping EXIT
Hangup
```

There may be a confused abandoned cat though:

```
cat: -: Input/output error
```

To solve this, you may want to search and kill child processes from a function called by the trap.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
$ ./test-trap
We are 24814
^CTrapping EXIT
```

Now, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the cat command ends normally. But then the trap is executed when the script ends:

```
$ ./test-trap
We are 40183
# I pressed Ctrl+D here...
Trapping EXIT
```

You can prevent that by unsetting the trap at the end of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "We are $$"
trap "echo 'Trapping EXIT'" EXIT
cat
trap - EXIT
```

I was unable to find any documentation for this different behaviour of trapping EXIT. Perhaps someone else can?