# Why does bash 'read' exit with status 1?

Tags: bash, read

From an answer to ["Bash script doesn't see SIGHUP?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387847/bash-script-doesnt-see-sighup), I've got the following in my script:

```
while true; do read; done
```

And, usually, this works fine. However, when run from (tl;dr) ... something else, `read` exits with status code 1.

Why? And how can I deal with this and restore the desired behaviour (correctly triggering the `EXIT` trap)?

---

(The "something else" is *GNU make* running *Erlang's `ct_run`*, which uses *`erlexec`* to run *the script*)

Comment: When you run the code from _something else_, does it have a standard input stream?

Comment: What is that loop supposed to do? You don't seem to be using the value read by `read`, and neither is the exit code checked...

Comment: "Does it have a standard input stream?". Probably not. How do I check?

Comment: The loop is supposed to allow interruption with Ctrl+C, so that the EXIT trap is run. Using something like a simple `cat` at the end of the script allows Ctrl+C, but doesn't run the trap.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` documentation in the `bash` man page says

> The exit status is zero,
>                 unless end-of-file is encountered, `read` times out (in which case the status  is  greater  than  128),  a
>                 variable assignment error (such as assigning to a readonly variable) occurs, or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to `-u`.

In your case I suspect standard input is reaching end-of-file.

Since you’re trying to wait indefinitely while still allowing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, perhaps the following would work better:

```
while sleep 1; do :; done
```

This avoids surprises related to I/O handling and ensures a timely reaction to signals.