# source a long running script in background from bash_profile

Tags: bash, background-process

My `.bash_profile` script takes several seconds to run each time I am opening a terminal so this becomes quite annoying.

My testing shows that certain commands are taking a long time so I moved them out of `.bash_profile` to a new script `.bash_profile_load_in_background`

From `.bash_profile` I am trying to source in the background.

```
.bash_profile

# fast stuff here

#.....

# slow stuff here

source .bash_profile_load_in_background & # notice the &
```

In `.bash_profile_load_in_background` I am setting some variables but they are not propogated correctly when the `source` is sent to background `&`.

here is an abridged version of my "slow" script:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

if type brew &>/dev/null; then
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX="$(brew --prefix)"
  if [[ -r "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]]; then
    source "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
  else
    for COMPLETION in "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/bash_completion.d/"*; do
      [[ -r "$COMPLETION" ]] && source "$COMPLETION"
    done
  fi
fi

if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
 . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

# parse the git branch
gb() {
     __git_ps1
}

# change the prompt to show working directory and git branch
PS1="\[\e[32m\]\w \[\e[91m\]\$(gb)\[\e[00m\]? "
```

Easy enough to see that the `PS1` prompt isn't changing once the script in the background has completed.

On the other hand if I source the script in "blocking" inline fashion, everything works as expected:

i.e.

Modify

`source .bash_profile_load_in_background & # notice the &`

to

`source .bash_profile_load_in_background # REMOVE THE &`

Why is this happening?

Any way to make this work and speed up the `.bash_profile` load time in a simple fashion? I don't care if some the functionality takes several seconds to take effect, but it must take effect in the current scope.

Answer (score 5):

#### Trick

[This other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664044/108618) explains why your attempt doesn't work. There's a trick to make it work, at least to some degree. I don't really recommend it, it's not how `.bash_profile` is supposed to work.

Here's the idea:

1. Let `.bash_profile` create a temporary file and remember the path to it:

   ```
   tmpf="$(mktemp)"
   ```

   <sup>(`mktemp` is not portable.)</sup>
2. Set a `trap`, so the shell sources the temporary file upon `SIGUSR1`. After sourcing, the file and the trap are no longer needed, so consider cleaning as a part of the trap.

   ```
   trap '
     . "$tmpf"
     rm "$tmpf"
     trap - USR1
   ' USR1
   ```
3. Run `.bash_profile_background_wizard` in the background. This script must be able to write to the temporary file, so give it a descriptor or the path (as an argument or in the environment). Example:

   ```
   tmpf="$tmpf" ~/.bash_profile_background_wizard &
   ```

   The script should start the long-running tasks and write shell code into the temporary file. It should *build* definitions of functions and variables, anything that depends on the long-running tasks, anything you want the main shell to "adopt" when it's ready. Depending on what you want to do, it may not be easy to write a script that writes a script. Remember the temporary file is about to be *parsed* by the main shell. `declare -p variable >>"$tmpf"` or the syntax `${variable@Q}` will be useful.

   After writing all the code to the temporary file, the script should send `SIGUSR1` to the main shell

   ```
   kill -s USR1 "$PPID"
   ```

   and exit.
4. Thanks to the trap the main shell will source the code prepared by `.bash_profile_background_wizard`.

---

#### Notes

- If the signal comes when the main shell is waiting for some synchronous command to complete then [the trap will not be executed until the command completes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387854/108618).
- If you spawn a child `bash` before the signal comes, don't expect the child to react to the signal. Because:

  - it won't get the signal due to having a different PID,
  - it won't inherit the trap.

  Note if you spawn a child `bash` in a way that causes it to source `.bash_profile` then the whole trick will start for the child `bash` *independently*.
- If you spawn a background process before the signal comes, don't expect the environment of the process to be updated when the main shell finally sources the temporary file and possibly changes its own environment.
- If you exit the main shell before the trap runs then the temporary file will remain (`trap '…' EXIT` may be handy).

---

#### Proof of concept

The following snippet is designed to be pasted into an interactive Bash. This way you can test the idea without polluting your `.bash_profile`. The mechanics is the same as presented above.

```bash
# imagine this block is sourced from .bash_profile
{
export PS1='poor prompt > '
tmpf="$(mktemp)"
trap '
  . "$tmpf"
  rm "$tmpf"
  trap - USR1
' USR1
# wizard in background
tmpf="$tmpf" bash -c '
  sleep 10  # delay
  PS1="RICH PROMPT >>> "
  declare -p PS1 >>"$tmpf"
  kill -s USR1 "$PPID"
' &
}
# Initially you will see a poor prompt.
# Run few basic commands or keep striking Enter.
# After 10 seconds the prompt should change.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to combine two incompatible things.

The `source` command makes the shell read a file and execute the commands therein *in the current shell environment*.

Starting an asynchronous job, i.e. running a command in the background with `&`, runs the command in its own environment, separate from the invoking shell.  This environment is a copy of the parent shells environment and it will be destroyed as the command terminates.  There is no way for the background job to set environment variables etc. in the parent shell's environment.

The effect of your command

```bsh
source .bash_profile_load_in_background &
```

is that `bash` starts a new shell process (in the background) in which it runs the `source` command.  That process then dies, and the modified environment with it.

The effect is the same as if you had run the `.bash_profile_load_in_background` as a separate *script* (which also runs in its own environment).

Related:

- [What scopes can shell variables have?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/what-scopes-can-shell-variables-have)
- [How can I make environment variables "exported" in a shell script stick around?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/how-can-i-make-environment-variables-exported-in-a-shell-script-stick-around)

Comment: so how can i speed up things or cache this between terminals? I split my terminal a lot and this delay is very annoying

Comment: @AvnerBarr This is something that you may want to ask another question about. This was not what you current question was aiming at, and what "NVM" is and how `bash` completions work on macOS (which I'm presuming you're using based on the use of the `brew` command and mentionings of "Homebrew") is something I'm blissfully unaware of.

Comment: What is actually taking the time?  The nvm invocation?